# Python: Set timezone of dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, timezone

Hi I am looking for a python command to set a timezone to a specific column.

Particularly my dataframe looks like below and I would like "to say" column "Date" is a date in Europe/Berlin timezone. I do not want to convert this time to Europe, this means 11:02:31 +2:00 is not correct. Do you have any idea to set this time to Europe/Berlin time?

```
   Index                Date  Stamp (s)     Value       Epoch
0      0 2016-07-06 11:02:31  0.1250000 0.0169273  1467802951
1      1 2016-07-06 11:02:32  1.1250000 0.0168724  1467802952
2      2 2016-07-06 11:02:33  2.1250000 0.0168620  1467802953
3      3 2016-07-06 11:02:34  3.1400000 0.0169068  1467802954
4      4 2016-07-06 11:02:35  4.1400000 0.0168702  1467802955
```

Greets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tz_localize.

```
  df = df.assign(Date=df['Date'].dt.tz_localize('Europe/Berlin'))
```

nb: I prefer to use assign to avoid trying to set data to a view.

Answer (score 1):

```
# core modules
from datetime import timezone, datetime

# 3rd party modules
import pandas as pd
import pytz

# create a dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [datetime(2018, 12, 30, 20 + i, 56)
                        for i in range(2)]},)
print(df)

# Convert the time to a timezone-aware datetime object
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_localize(timezone.utc)
print(df)

# Convert the time from to another timezone
# The point in time does not change, only the associated timezone
my_timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.tz_convert(my_timezone)
print(df)
```